# How do i dynamically/evaluate via expression json property in django template

Tags: django-templates

reading in a JSON for sport. using a partial for matchup markup.
awayteam and home team for most part share identical markup but the JSON properties which I have no control are such below:

```
<div class="away {{game.awayTeam_last_name|slugify}}">
  <a href="#" title="{{game.awayTeam_first_name}} {{game.awayTeam_last_name}}">
    <span class="{{league}}-logo"></span>
<span class="city">{{game.awayTeam_first_name}}</span>
    {% if game.event_status != "pre-event" %}
      <span title="score">{{game.awayTeam_score}}</span>
    {% else %}
      <span title="record entering game">(0-0)</span>
    {% endif %}
  </a>
</div>
<span>@</span>
<div class="home {{game.homeTeam_last_name|slugify}}">
  <a href="#" title="{{game.homeTeam_first_name}} {{game.homeTeam_last_name}}">
    <span class="{{league}}-logo"></span>
    <span class="city">{{game.homeTeam_first_name}}</span>
    {% if game.event_status != "pre-event" %}
      <span title="score">{{game.homeTeam_score}}</span>
    {% else %}
      <span title="record entering game">(0-0)</span>
    {% endif %}  
  </a>
</div>
```

is there a way to shrink/refactor the above like some expression valuator to make home and away passed via a variable.

Answer (score 0):

didn't answer own question but i did get Data guys to better format the data, so became..
awayteam: { first_name:'', last_name:'',  score:''  }
hometeam: { first_name:'', last_name:'',  score:''  }

allowing me to shrink in half the template =)